# Soundmanager2, Safari and PHP streaming error

Tags: php, safari, streaming, soundmanager2

I am using soundmanager2 and I have a problem with Safari.

I am successfully streaming protected files (outside the webroot) from PHP to Soundmanager2, using something like this :

```
//check if user is logged in and has rights on $file
//if yes stream file

        if (file_exists($file)) { 
            $filepath = $file;
            $filesize = filesize($filepath);

            header("Pragma: no-cache");
            header("Expires: 0");
            header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
            header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
            header('Content-Length: '.$filesize);
            @readfile($filepath);
            exit(0);
        }
```

This works fine on Firefox and Chrome, the mp3 files are playing, but in Safari I get :

```
soundmanager2.js:1190basicMP3Sound0: Using HTML5
soundmanager2.js:1190basicMP3Sound0: play(): Attempting to load
soundmanager2.js:1190basicMP3Sound0: load (/privateaccess/index/1415)
soundmanager2.js:1190basicMP3Sound0: waiting
soundmanager2.js:1190basicMP3Sound0: loadstart
soundmanager2.js:1190basicMP3Sound0: loadedmetadata
soundmanager2.js:1190basicMP3Sound0: HTML5 error, code 3
soundmanager2.js:1188basicMP3Sound0: Failed to load / invalid sound? Zero-length duration reported. (/privateaccess/index/1415)
```

I only get this error when I stream a file from PHP, it's working with files that are in the webroot (delivered by apache instead of PHP).

If I hit www.myurl.com/privateaccess/index/1415 directly, the file is downloaded, so it really seems like an issue between Safari,Soundmanager2 and PHP file streaming.

Anyone? an idea to fix/workaround this?

Answer (score 5):

You need to support byte range requests. [See SoundManager2's Technical Notes on the subject.](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/technotes/#byte-serving)

Example Request:

```
GET some.ogg HTTP/1.1
Range: bytes=5210604-5275910
```

Expected Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-length: 65307
Content-Range: bytes 5210604-5275910/5275911
Content-Type: audio/ogg
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  Not sure how i missed it on their site, but thankfully you added the relevant link here.